# How to extract text from Dynamic captcha image using R Programming?

Tags: r, text, ocr, tesseract, captcha

I have a Dynamic CAPTCHA image which contains text. Now, if I want to extract the text from the image, how can I do that?

So far, I have come up with the following code below:

```
library(tesseract)

eng <- tesseract("eng")

text <- tesseract::ocr("https://farm2.sat.gob.gt/saqbe-arancel-publico/Kaptcha.jpg", engine = eng)

cat(text)
```

The above code helps to extract text from the image, however, it is not a expected output text from image. How is it achievable using R? I would be really thankful if someone could help me in this problem.

Comment: The whole _point_ of Captcha is to make it extremely difficult for a computer to read the text in it. That is why Captcha exists. If one could simply get some code on Stack Overflow that could reliably extract text from Captcha, then it would then be easy to write a program that gets past Captchas on-line, and they would become redundant as a security measure. If anyone did have an algorithm to reliably extract text from Captchas, they would be unlikely to give it away for free on a public forum. Or do I misunderstand what you are asking?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.